# How to load information every minute in android?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that shows the results of soccer matches live. I load data via Json request with the library volley. Let me know if I can make that request every minute.

Is there any method similar to setInterval in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override 
    public void run() {
         doSomething();
         mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
    }
};
```

call `mHandlerTask.run();` whenever you want to start the task and replace `doSomething()` function with your volley request code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(N_THREADS);

ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do your business here
    }
}, DELAY, PERIOD, TIME_UNIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alarm receiver instead .
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

refer this link